# Research on reasons how vasectomy fails

Tags: reference-request, obstetrics, fertility

Commonly referred number is that in 1:1000 cases of vasectomy pregnancy can still happen (with same partner).

How many such cases have been really studied so far where a pregnancy took place after vasectomy?
Alone in US these must be then about 500 cases annually.

https://www.webmd.com/men/features/vasectomy-risks-benefits

Now what are exactly reasons for that and can this be predicted through monitoring of these factors?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how many patients have been studied in all the studies ever conducted on vasectomies? Or are you asking about the reasons for the failures? Those are explained in the article you linked, so I just don't know what you're asking.

Comment: I look for statistical data on failure cases distribution abd prevention studies, more than just examples.

Comment: http://www.contraceptivetechnology.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CTFailureTable.pdf

Comment: @Carey Gregory - I seek to understand what's in the 1:2000 chance of the self-healing and how dast does this develop on long term.

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify that. In particularly, asking how many such cases have been studied is misleading. That appears to be what you're asking.